# Finding all child elements with onmouseover

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have a xpath and I want to find all the child elements (even the nested child elements) which have onmouseover event attached to them. I am novel to Javascript and JQuery. Can someone please help me out?

For e.g. on the [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XF1XOQ), I want to get all the child elements with `onmouseover` for the first element with class `crAvgStars`.

Comment: Could you provide a code exemple?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("yourElementSelector").mouseover(function(){
    var children = $(this).children();
    // OR
    $(this).children().each(function(){
         // DO something with each one...
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/children/